# $a_{n+1}a_n=a_n^2+a_n+1$, $a_1=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$a_{n+1}a_n=a_n^2+a_n+1$, $a_1=1$,how to find integer $k$, make $\left|\sqrt{a_{2020}}-k\right|$ as small as possible.

Using computer, I get $a_{2020}\approx 2027.38$. then $\sqrt{a_{2020}}\approx 45.0264,k=45$

But without computer, how to calculate it?

I notice that **if** $\sqrt{a_{2020}}=XXX.6$,etc ,then $k=XXX+1$, else $k=XXX$. But then my  ideas stuck.

Comment: So what’s the closest integer to the square root of this number?

Comment: Is the sequence geometric or arithmetic?

Comment: We have: $a_1=1, \quad a_2=3, \quad 3a_3=13 \iff a_3=\frac{13}{3}$, so the sequence is neither geometric nor arithmetic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a_1 = 1,
a_{n+1} 
= a_n+1+\frac{1}{a_n}
$.

Then $a_n > n$
and
$a_{n+1} > a_n$.

$\begin{array}\\
a_{m+1}-a_1
&=\sum_{n=1}^m (a_{n+1}-a_n)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^m (1+\dfrac1{a_n})\\
&<m+\sum_{n=1}^m \dfrac1{n}\\
&=m+H_m\\
&< m+\ln(m)+1\\
\end{array}
$

so
$a_{m+1}
\lt m+\ln(m)+2
$.

$\dfrac1{a_m}
\gt \dfrac1{m+1+\ln(m-1)}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
a_{m+1}-a_1
&=\sum_{n=1}^m (a_{n+1}-a_n)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^m (1+\dfrac1{a_n})\\
&=m+\sum_{n=1}^m \dfrac1{a_n}\\
&=m+1+\sum_{n=2}^m \dfrac1{a_n}\\
&>m+1+\sum_{n=2}^m (\dfrac1{n+\ln(n)+1}-\dfrac1{n})+H_n-1\\
&=m-\sum_{n=2}^m \dfrac{\ln(n)+1}{n(n+\ln(n)+1)}+H_m\\
&>m+H_m-1.1\\
&>m+\ln(m)+.5-1.1\\
&=m+\ln(m)-0.6\\
\end{array}
$

so
$a_{m+1}
\gt m+\ln(m)+.4
$.

Therefore
$a_{2020}
\gt 2028.01
$
and
$a_{2020}
\lt 2029.7
$
so
$45.03
\lt \sqrt{a_{2020}}
\lt 45.052
$.

Therefore $k = 45$.

Answer (score 5):

We may note that our sequence is increasing, so it makes sense to rewrite the rule giving the sequence as $a_{n+1} = a_n+1+\frac{1}{a_n}$. The idea is to show that the contribution of the $\frac{1}{a_n}$ term is small, and in particular won't affect the estimate for what the square root is in this case.

Let $H_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1i$, the $n^{th}$ harmonic number. Then for $n>1$, we have that $n + 1 \leq a_n \leq n+H_{n-1}$ by induction, which is relatively straightforwards. As $H_n \sim \ln n + \gamma +O(\frac 1n)$, this gives that $H_{2020}$ is approximately $\ln 2020$, which is certainly no more than $11$, as $2^{11}= 2048$. So $2021\leq a_{2020} \leq 2031$, and as $2025=45^2$, we see that $k$ must be $45$.